# WordPress Registration with only email

Tags: php, wordpress

I looking for a plugin or custom coding solution that a user only needs to type in his mail adress for register. no username, no password.

I found this plugin, but the last update is two years ago.. https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-wp-login/

Answer (score 8):

**YES**, you can achieve this.

**Rule 1:** WordPress requires a username. We must provide a username.

**Rule 2:** Don't edit WordPress core code.

We can achieve this by hiding username field, get email and store it as username.

**Step-1:** Remove Username textfield

```
add_action('login_head', function(){
?>
<style>
    #registerform > p:first-child{
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#registerform > p:first-child').css('display', 'none');
    });
</script>
<?php
});
```

**Step-2:** Remove Username error

```
//Remove error for username, only show error for email only.
add_filter('registration_errors', function($wp_error, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email){
if(isset($wp_error->errors['empty_username'])){
    unset($wp_error->errors['empty_username']);
}

if(isset($wp_error->errors['username_exists'])){
    unset($wp_error->errors['username_exists']);
}
return $wp_error;
}, 10, 3);
```

**Step-3:** Manipulate Background Registration Functionality.

```
add_action('login_form_register', function(){
if(isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_email'])){
    $_POST['user_login'] = $_POST['user_email'];
}
});
```

Put above code in your **theme's functions.php** file.